# How do I repeat an expression over and over without having to copy and paste it all the time?

Tags: r

I created a function that contains a series of subtractions and additions with various objects that is in the input of the function, I would like to know how to perform these operations without having to copy and paste the existing code each time I add a new object.

```r
a <- function(qt1,qt2,qt3,qt4,
              cu1,cu2,cu3,cu4,
              gpd1,gpd2,gpd3,gpd4,
              cs1,cs2,cs3,cs4,
              csp1,csp2,csp3,csp4,
              cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,
              ms1,ms2,ms3,ms4,
              ad1,ad2,ad3,ad4)

{
  c1 = (qt1 * cu1) +gpd1 + cs1 + csp1+ce+cp1
  c2 = (qt2 * cu2) +gpd2 + cs2 + csp2+ce+cp2
  c3 = (qt3 * cu3) +gpd3 + cs3 + csp3+ce+cp3
  c4 = (qt4 * cu4) +gpd4 + cs4 + csp4+ce+cp4

  ct1 = (c1 * 0.4)+c1 + e/4+cap+ ms1+ qt1 *ad1
  ct2 = (c2 * 0.4)+c2 + e/4+cap+ ms2+ qt2 *ad2
  ct3 = (c1 * 0.4)+c3 + e/4+cap+ ms3+ qt3 *ad3
  ct4 = (c1 * 0.4)+c4 + e/4+cap+ ms4+ qt4 *ad4

  print("RU 1")
  print(ct1/qt1)
  print("RU 2")
  print(ct2/qt2)
  print("RU 3")
  print(ct3/qt3)
  print("RU 4")
  print(ct4/qt4)
}

a(qt1=10,qt2=15,qt3=18,qt4=20,
  cu1=5,cu2=2,cu3=12,cu4=17,
  gpd1=2,gpd2=5,gpd3=8,gpd4=8,
  cs1=2,cs2=4,cs3=2,cs4=5,
  csp1=2,csp2=3,csp3=4,csp4=4,
  cp1=2,cp2=2,cp3=2,cp4=2,
  ms1=2,ms2=2,ms3=4,ms4=5,
  ad1=1,ad2=2,ad3=3,ad4=4)
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'add a new object'?

Comment: in this code I have the operations for 4 "objects"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also treat your parameters as features.

```
library(tidyverse)


df_example <- tribble(~cu,~q,~gpd,~cs,~csp,~ce,~cp,~e,~cap,~qt,~ms,~ad,
                      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,
                      2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24)



df_example %>% 
  mutate(c = (qt * cu) +gpd + cs + csp+ce+cp,
         ct = (c * 0.4) + c + e/4+cap+ms+qt+ad,
         result = ct/qt) %>% 
  pull(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty simple. Make use of vectors instead of passing each as an individual argument.

```r
# qt <- c(qt1, qt2, qt3, qt4)
# cu <- c(cu1, cu2, cu3, cu4)

qt <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
cu <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

All the operations will work just the same on the vectors, so you don't have to explicitly perform the expression over and over again.

```r
# Addition/Subtraction
qt + cu
[1] 2 4 6 8

# Multiplication
qt * cu
[1]  1  4  9 16

# Division
qt / 2
[1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In R like many data science tools, learn to use collections like data frames to run needed analyses across many data points. Hence, to piggyback off of skillsmuggler's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59415924/1422451), consider using a data frame which in R is a `class` object that extends the `list` type comprised of equal length atomic vectors.

With this approach, you can go beyond just four "objects" to potentially infinite rows without changing calculation code or having to print single items. However, your data originally comes in wide format (denoted by suffixed names). But if you `reshape` to long format, you can effortlessly run formulaic calculations. See this [demo](https://rextester.com/SHLJ77091) migrating your input values to long format as shown below.

```
long_df
#     id qt cu gpd cs csp cp ms ad
# 1 RU 1 10  5   2  2   2  2  2  1
# 2 RU 2 15  2   5  4   3  2  2  2
# 3 RU 3 18 12   8  2   4  2  4  3
# 4 RU 4 20 17   8  5   4  2  5  4

# CALCULATIONS
long_df<- within(long_df, {    
    c <- (qt * cu) + gpd + cs + csp + ce + cp
    ct <- (c * 0.4)+c + e/4+cap+ ms+ qt * ad

    ratio <- ct/qt
})

long_df[c("id", "ratio")]
#     id     ratio
# 1 RU 1  9.685000
# 2 RU 2  6.483333
# 3 RU 3 21.469444
# 4 RU 4 29.562500
```

Which replicates your print output with same unknown input as `e <- 1`, `ce <- 1`, `cap <- 2`.

```
# [1] "RU 1"
# [1] 9.685
# [1] "RU 2"
# [1] 6.483333
# [1] "RU 3"
# [1] 17.60278
# [1] "RU 4"
# [1] 23.5425
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way to turn ct output into vectors? i need some way to identify them individually

Comment: Since a data frame is a list of vectors, every column *is* a vector. For `ct`, output `long_df$ct` and likewise all others. Here I just display (no change to data) the columns: `id` and `ratio`.

Comment: I used the exact same code but now for 5, and it only returns me a df for the previous four, do i have to change anything else??df <- data.frame (qt1=10,qt2=15,qt3=18,qt4=20,qt5=1,
                 cu1=5,cu2=2,cu3=12,cu4=17,cu5=1,
                 gpd1=2,gpd2=5,gpd3=8,gpd4=8,gdp5=1,
                 cs1=2,cs2=4,cs3=2,cs4=5,cs5=5,
                 csp1=2,csp2=3,csp3=4,csp4=4,csp5=1,
                 cp1=2,cp2=2,cp3=2,cp4=2,cp5=1,
                 ms1=2,ms2=2,ms3=4,ms4=5,ms5=5,
                 ad1=1,ad2=2,ad3=3,ad4=4,ad5=1)

Comment: You misspelled the *gpd* series for 5. Adjust and five rows should return per demo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I was adding more rows to the dataframe until it stopped doing the ru1-ru2-ru3 logical sequence and it was ru10, why did that happen? how to fix? https://imgur.com/EHsvWal

Comment: That's simply the alphabet order of columns. Since numbers are treated as strings it arranges that way. But use factor levels to retain needed order. In demo, change `id` assignment to: `id = factor(paste("RU", 1:ncol(sub)), levels = paste("RU", 1:ncol(sub)))`.

Comment: I tried the new code and still have the same problem https://imgur.com/Gi6lq7b

Comment: It should: https://rextester.com/UJXSN15822. Honestly, I do not know how you are implementing this solution. Overall, try working in data.frames in long format and not one-item values. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: https://rextester.com/YFVB21167 my code looks exactly like this

Comment: Add the argument `sort = FALSE` in `merge`: https://rextester.com/UZU3096.